# How can I find a lost (tamed) dino?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

I went on a resource run with a Quetz, perched it on a cliff, and (I assume) it got attacked while I was exploring. It had a lot of health and melee damage, so I think it probably survived the fight and just landed somewhere in the forest. I've tried scouting the area with another flying mount, whistling and using a telescope as I search, but no luck so far. Sadly, it did not have a transponder attached.

With the recent advent of admin commands on console, I started wondering if there was a way to teleport that missing Quetz to my location, or reveal it on the map somehow. Is there any command or technique you can use to locate a nearby, but hidden, tamed dino? Or bring it to your location automatically?

EDIT:

To clarify, I want *this* dino back. I am aware that dinos can be spawned via commands. I want to find out how to recover this dino, with all its inventory.

Comment: I had the same thing happen to me two days ago.  Was going on a metal run and my Ptera and I got attacked by a Raptor (or something along those lines).  And that was that.  The Ptera didn't die.  As far as I could tell. Grumble.... Oh well.  Tamed another one at a much lower level.

Answer (score 4):

When a tamed dino dies you get a message in the log section. So if you don't have a message there, it most certainly survived.

Personally... I have lost a ptera for about 2 weeks then found him. I lost another 1 and after about other 2 weeks it died of hunger.

Now... about finding him (I haven't play for about 2 months, but I think the further are still valid).

1. If when you died it was on passive and **not on follow**, it should be exactly where you left it (even if you were mid air). Dinos don't consume stamina while not mounted.
2. If it was on aggresive/neutral and **not on follow**, it should be in the area fighting dinos.
3. If it was on follow and you die... it just goes crazy and flies randomly (in my cases once went as high up as it could get and once at the border of the map). When this happens I usually consider it lost.
4. About commands, afaik they only work on private servers, not on official.

Source: Personal XP, about 300h of gameplay, also about 400h for my wife.

Comment: Thanks for tips, it is a private server so commands are applicable, but I will see if maybe the quetz is flying at the map border or something.

Answer (score 2):

Usually when this occurs your Dino gets glitched under the map, or it flies above the top of the map. It will usually appear randomly across the map, it's most commonly found in 0,0 cords

Answer (score -3):

So dude, just spawn a new dino. For example: `admincheat summon argent_character_bp_c`
And mount it with a saddle, then type `admincheat addexperience 1000 0 0`