# Can't find lost mount

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

I was taming a Pteranodon and already had a Pelagornis. When the Pteranodon was tamed I realized it was on 'attack my target' (as they are when first tamed) so I changed it to passive. Then I realized that my Pelagornis was also on neutral. I don't like having flyers on neutral because when they get attacked they go absolutely mental. I was in the menu when i tried to click 'change aggression level to:Passive' when I slipped and must of clicked 'enable wandering' because he kicked me out of the menu and the Pelagornis flew off into the sky. I tried to press U and J to get him to come back but he was already out of range. I could have followed but I didn't have the Pteranodon saddle ready so I had to go and gather resources. I have flown across the entire: south, north and west of the map looking for him.

Basically I was just wondering if there is a command to locate him, or teleport him to me. And it is on a singleplayer so I don't have to worry about it being an official and not letting me. Please help!!!

Comment: Sort of a duplicate of my question [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/262251/108888) though i did not have wandering enabled, which changes the scenario slightly

Comment: Ive been unable to find a working answer though, unfortunately

Comment: well, thanks anyway. I think i might have actually read your post, because i did read a couple of posts and none could help. as i said, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In-game, there's no method to find a lost dinosaur, unless you've already placed a tracking node on the dinosaur (assuming it has not been removed.)

If mods are an option, the one I've used, for years is: [Joan's Pet Finder](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=566887000)  It will basically show a line pointing in the direction of your pets (except those close to you) to help you find them.

Related, you can also use her [Death Helper](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=566885854), which works along the same premise, to find your corpse when you die.